# Hyperledger Fabric Server with node sdk slow on query or invoke while internet not connected

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I have written some server and tested its working in the ubuntu desktop edition. It is working fine as expected. I tested it without internet it is working. The problem is when i deploy it into the ubuntu server edition it is working fine as long as the internet is connected to the vm. when i remove the internet connection i.e turning off the http and https port the node server works fine but when i query / invoke chaincode it is going very slow to the dev peer which results in timeout error after 45 seconds. After it goes to chaincode and store or query it again takes time to come back to the server till then the server is also close.
this is how i am sending the request to chaincode

```
            targets: peerNames,
            chaincodeId: chaincodeName,
            fcn: fcn,
            args: args,
            chainId: channelName,
            txId: tx_id
        };

        logger.debug("request ---------", request);
        
        let results = await channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);
```

it gets struck at after this and sent the request to dev peer very slow.
similar query code

```
            targets: peer, //queryByChaincode allows for multiple targets
            chaincodeId: chaincodeName,
            fcn: fcn,
            args: args
        };
            // logger.debug("request " + request.args);
            console.log("querying cc");
            var t1=Date.now();
            console.log(t1);

        let response_payloads = await channel.queryByChaincode(request);
```

I am struck at this moment in the ubuntu server edition with out the internet . This works fine in desktop edition with out the internet.